# Struct Array Bug

Tags: c, struct, extern

[image]

Hi All, 
from the above image.
I am able to compile, but the program crashes at runtime. 
Please advise me what could be the resolution to solve this?
Thank you

**// structArray.h:**

```
 #ifndef __STRUCTARRAY_H_
 #define __STRUCTARRAY_H_


typedef struct _vector{
     int* str;  
     int     maskSize;  
     // etc...
 }__attribute__((__packed__)) _vector_t;

 #endif /* _STRUCTARRAY_H_ */

**// do_structArray.c**

#include "structArray.h"

extern struct _vector_t t;

void do_structArray (void) {

int plaintext[2] = {0x05, 0x08};

_vector_t t[] = {
    {plaintext, sizeof(plaintext)},
    //{},
};

  printf("Content: \n%x \n", t[1].str[1]);  
}

// main : just calling do_structArray
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "structArray.h"

extern struct _vector_t t;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {    
do_structArray();

  system("PAUSE");  
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Array indices begin from 0 in C. You're accessing an array element past the end of the array. Change the index to 0:

```
printf("Content: \n%x \n", t[0].str[0]);
```

Comment: I am sorry. Late nights programming is really getting into me. This is correct.
Thank you for helping me.

Answer (score 4):

You are accessing `t[1]` but only have one item in `t`. Try `printf("Content: \n%x \n", t[0].str[1])`.